# Time complexity formula of nested loops

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I've just begun this stage 2 Compsci paper on algorithms, and stuff like this is not my strong point. I've come across this in my lecture slides.

```
int length = input.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        System.out.println(input.substring(i,j));
    }
}
```

"In each iteration, the outer loop executes $\frac{n^{2}-(2i-1)n-i+i^{2}}{2}$ operations from the inner loop for $i = 0, \ldots, n-1$."

Can someone please explain this to me step by step?

I believe the formula above was obtained by using Gauss' formula for adding numbers... I think...

Comment: Are you assuming that printing each character in the string is 1 operation?  Do we add one for the newline printed by println?

Comment: Just as some formatting help, stackexchange sites can do most TeX maths formatting, so you can put your maths between dollar signs ($) and get maths stuff. I'll edit your post to use this so you get an example.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, to get the formula to match the lecture slides, it seems that we have to assume printing each character is 1 operation, but that the newline is ignored. For some reason. Ofcourse it probably should have the newline as an operation too, but whoever wrote it seems to have ignored that. Or I added it up wrong. That's also quite possible.

Comment: Note that $i=0, \dots, n-2$. Or is $n = \mathtt{input.length()} - 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, the work is in identifying the things you're adding together.

The first bit is that printing a string of length $m$ takes $m$ operations, so the

```
System.out.println(input.substring(i,j));
```

line takes $j-i$ operations. (A side note here is that this code is in Java, unless I'm very much mistaken, and the `substring(start, end)` method gives the substring beginning at index `start` and ending at `end-1`)

So then at each iteration of the outer loop, we're printing a bunch of substrings, starting with a string of length one (just the character at index $i$) and ending with the substring that starts at $i$ and goes to the end of the string `input`.

To put that a dash more mathematically we're printing strings of length $1, 2, \ldots, n-i$. As the number of operations  required to print a string is the same as its length, we're doing $\sum_{k=1}^{n-i}k$ operations. Substituting Gauss's formula for this sum, we get that the number of operations is equal to:
$$
\frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}
$$

Then multiplying everything out gives the formula you have in your slides.

Comment: Thank you, I see now that the problem was not actually in my understanding. I was expanding out the formula really wrongly.

Comment: I saw your related question on math.SE, so between these two, hopefully it all makes sense :).

Answer (score 3):

Let's work from the outside in.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
```

Clearly, this loop is executed $n = \mathtt{length}-1$ times, so we get $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dots$ where $\dots$ stands for the time needed by the loop's body (for iteration $i$). Inside, we have

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
```

which we can translate similarly, obtaining $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j = i+1}^{n} \dots$. Last but not least, the innermost operation

```
    System.out.println(input.substring(i,j));
```

is apparently assumed to take $j-i$ steps (one operation per character).

Putting everything together, we get

$\qquad \begin{align}
  T(n) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j = i+1}^{n} j - i \\
       &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left[\left(\sum_{j = i+1}^{n} j\right) - (n-i)i\right] \\
       &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left[\left(\sum_{j = 1}^{n} j - \sum_{j = 1}^{i} j\right) - (n-i)i\right] \\
       &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left[\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{i(i+1)}{2}\right) - (n-i)i\right] \\
       &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left[ \frac{n^2 - (2i - 1)n + i^2 - i}{2}\right]
\end{align}$

The term in brackets is what you are looking for.

The whole sum can be evaluated using Gauss' formula and its [sibling for summand $i^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number):

$\qquad \begin{align}
 2T(n) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} n^2 - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2in + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2 - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i \\ 
      &= n^3 - 2n \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i + n^2 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2 - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i \\ 
      &= n^3 - n^2(n-1) + n^2 + \frac{(n-1)n(2n - 1)}{6} - \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \\
      &= \frac{12n^2 + 2n^3 - 3n^2 + n - 3n^2 + 3n}{6} \\
      &= \frac{2n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n}{6}
\end{align}$

which immediately yields

$\qquad \displaystyle T(n) = \frac{n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n}{6}$.

Comment: The final result is much nicer if we choose $n=\mathtt{length}$: $\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6}$.

Comment: Thank you for that, but admittedly the sum notation you used went way over my head. Do you think however you could explain where that final formula came from? T(n) = n^3... etc.

Comment: @yoonsi: I tried to write it down as small-stepped as necessary; there is nothing there but a) using distributive law to pull $i$ (not dependent on $j$) out of the sum, b) rewrite the inner sum into a difference of two sums starting at $1$, c) Gauss' formula. I'll edit in the major steps for the final result.

Comment: @yoonsi: If you want to get into algorithm analysis (either for fun or to pass an exam), you better get used to sum manipulation (among other things). The [TCS Cheat Sheet](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf) for identities and [Concrete Mathematics](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/gkp.html) for a more complete introduction and lots of exercises can be helpful resources. Beyond that, it's exercise.

Comment: Thanks for those resources! Yes, I know I'm far behind. At the school I'm at, this is the first paper that deals with algorithms on this mathematical level and I don't come from a maths background, but I'm trying. If you know of any other good resources, please let me know. I want to get better at this. I will definitely start exercising!