# How to find the asymptotic runtime of these nested loops?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

```
i=n; 
while(i>0) {
  k=1;
  for(j=1;j<=n:j+=k)
    k++;
  i=i/2;
}
```

The while loop has the complexity of $\lg(n)$ the j value of inner loop runs 1,3,6,10,15...
increase like 2,3,4,5,...

But how to find the overall complexity ?

Comment: u r genius @Raphael u r the 1st person to figure it out!!!

Comment: From your comments it seems as if you don't know even the basics of algorithm analysis. Please see many questions of the same kind ([1](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4800/98), [2](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2994/98), [3](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3306/98)) and [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions); they should contain everything you need in sufficient detail.

Comment: I misread the question earlier; the `k++` in the inner loop makes things more interesting. Still, please read the questions I linked and present a more elaborate attempt which we can then work off.

Comment: Please stop undoing edits that improve the question or its formatting.

Comment: pls remove dublicate tag @Raphael

Comment: As [I've said before](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/how-to-find-the-asymptotic-runtime-of-these-nested-loops?noredirect=1#comment39456_19480), as long as you don't include an elaboration on your thoughts, it remains a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$j$ satisfies the recurrence $j_k = j_{k-1}+k$. Note that another sequence, $s_k = k^2$ satisfies $s_k = s_{k-1} + 2k-1$.

$$j_k = \sum_{i=1}^k i = \frac 1 2\sum_{i=1}^k 2i = \frac 1 2(s_k+k)$$

This should give you enough to find the largest $k$ such that $j_k < n$.

Comment: why is the second relation needed can u explain @Karolis

Comment: @avi, which relation is the second? Are you asking why bother expressing $j_k$ in terms of $s_k$?

Comment: yes ,i cant figure it out .@Karolis

Comment: @avi, if the loop was `for(k = 1; s_k < n; k++)` the complexity would be $O(\sqrt n)$.

Comment: total complexity is then O(log n^3/2)@Karolis

Comment: @avi, I'm not sure where you put the parentheses in that, but no. You had already decided the total complexity would be $O(k\log n)$ and this isn't that.

Comment: So what is the complexity of the segment?@Karolis

Comment: @avi Translate the loops to sums and evaluate...